# (Eclipse) Can a Launch configuration exist only in one mode? Either Run or Debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, development-environment

Is there a way, that an Eclipse launch configuration exists **only** in one mode? Either  *Run* -or *Debugmode*. Until this point, I've only seen this mirror behaviour, that if I create a launch configuration in the *Run Configurations* menu (in Eclipse), it will also be created in the *Debug Configurations* menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Look at the debug configuration for "Remote Java Application". It isn't available in run mode.

The supported modes of the launch configurations are defined by the plug-ins with launch configuration type extension points.
See [Adding launchers to the platform](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_adding.htm)

Comment: Good example. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's not something users can control. The plugin providers creating the launch configuration type can decide whether it's Run, Debug or both.

See also http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_adding.htm